# return observable after obtaining promise value

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I have the following code but it dos not work,  and I would like to return an observable once the promise is resolved. Any ideas? Any suggestion is welcome

```
  getParalelos() {

    let _observable;
    this.getToken().subscribe(token => {
      _observable = this.http.get(`${this.url}/paralelo?token=${this.token}`, httpOptions)
    })
    return _observable;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flatMap.

http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

`import { flatMap } from "rxjs/operators";`

```
getParalelos() {
    return this.getToken().pipe(
        flatMap(token => {
            return this.http.get(`${this.url}/paralelo?token=${this.token}`, httpOptions)
        })
    );
}
```